# Error reading Stream on bean

Tags: jsf, stream

i'm trying to view a PDF using streamedcontenct but i still getting this error.

```
31-Mar-2017 10:26:32.796 INFORMACIÓN [http-apr-8080-exec-78] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
 java.io.IOException: javax.el.ELException: /ordenRetiro.xhtml @211,112 value="#{ordenRetiroBean.stream}": Error reading 'stream' en el tipo com.delpac.bean.OrdenRetiroBean
    at org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer.encodeEnd(MediaRenderer.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:186)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:115)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /ordenRetiro.xhtml @211,112 value="#{ordenRetiroBean.stream}": Error reading 'stream' en el tipo com.delpac.bean.OrdenRetiroBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at org.primefaces.component.media.Media.getValue(Media.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer.getMediaSrc(MediaRenderer.java:126)
    at org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer.encodeEnd(MediaRenderer.java:43)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'stream' en el tipo com.delpac.bean.OrdenRetiroBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullnull (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.delpac.bean.OrdenRetiroBean.getStream(OrdenRetiroBean.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    ... 58 more
```

My xhtml is this:
Command link to open p:dialog

```
<p:column  style="text-align: center">
  <p:commandLink ajax="true" id="icon-pdf" class="icon-edit" value="" 
  actionListener="#{ordenRetiroBean.showPDFDialog(ord)}" 
  oncomplete="PF('dlgReporte').show();" update="DialogPDF" />
</p:column>
```

The p:dialog code:

```
<p:dialog id="DialogPDF" widgetVar="dlgReporte" modal="true" closable="true" 
          closeOnEscape="true" width="900" height="350" header="Orden de Retiro">
   <h:form>
        <p:media value="#{ordenRetiroBean.stream}" height="600" width="600" player="pdf" />
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

My bean:
On constructor:

```
exportDir = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "\\OrdenesRetiro\\"; 
nom_archivo = "Orden_de_Retiro" + ord.getCod_ordenretiro() + ".pdf";
nom_archivo_sinext = "Orden_de_Retiro" + ord.getCod_ordenretiro();
```

I declared a StreamedContent variable calle "stream", so in the getter i set this:

```
public StreamedContent getStream() throws IOException{
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File(exportDir + nom_archivo)), "application/pdf", nom_archivo_sinext);
}
```

Feel free to ask if you need more info. I need to show this on a datatable that each row it's going to have the commandlink button, so when the user click on it, it shows a p:dialog with the PDF inside.

Comment: Jorge, this error message is not useful. It's just a summary message telling that "an error" has occurred. You should find the stack trace in server log and focus on the bottommost root cause for the actual error it is talking about. Interpreting of exceptions and stack traces  is not different for JSF applications than for basic Java applications.

Comment: @BalusC Hi Balus, i just updated the error message. Tell me if you need mroe info.

Comment: I can't explain it more clearer than the exception message itself: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullnull (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)` Can you please tell what part exactly of that message you didn't understand?